# Can this sql query be optimized for oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

### Message table

```
|-----|-------------|-----------------|--------|--------------|
|  id | message_id  | msg_connect_id  |  body  |  created_ts  |  
|-----|-------------|-----------------|--------|--------------|
|  1  | 12345       | 1234            |  body1 |  timestamp1  |
|  2  | 12346       | 1234            |  body2 |  timestamp2  |
|  3  | 12347       | 1234            |  body3 |  timestamp3  |
|  4  | 12348       | 5678            |  body4 |  timestamp4  |
|  5  | 12349       | 1234            |  body5 |  timestamp5  |
|-----|-------------|-----------------|--------|--------------|
```

Provided that message_id is a query parameter can this query be optimized?

```
SELECT id,message_id ,body,created_ts FROM message
where msg_connect_id = (select msg_connect_id from message where message_id ='12346')
and id <=  (select id from message where message_id ='12346') order by created_ts desc
```

I am expecting the row matching the message_id param along with all the rows below it with the same msg_connect_id.
So e.g. if the param message_id is 12346 then expected rows are rows with id 2, 3 and 5.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the subquery to the `from` clause and use indexes:

```
select m.id, m.message_id, m.body, m.created_ts 
from message m cross join
     (select m2.*
      from message m2
      where message_id = 12346  -- it looks like a number, so I assume it is
     ) mm
where m.msg_connect_id = mm.msg_connect_id and
      m.id <= mm.id
order by m.created_ts desc;
```

For this, you want indexes on `(message_id)` and `(msg_connect_id, id)`.

Comment: I just had to change the comparison operator to <= and rest worked fine. Thanks